# How would you model this in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database-schema, nosql

There are products with a name and price.

Users log about products they have bought.

```
# option 1: embed logs
product = { id, name, price }
user = { id, 
         name,
         logs : [{ product_id_1, quantity, datetime, comment },
                 { product_id_2, quantity, datetime, comment },
                 ... ,
                 { product_id_n, quantity, datetime, comment }] 
}
```

I like this. But if product ids are 12 bytes long, quantity and datetime are 32-bit (4 bytes) integers and comments 100 bytes on average, then the size of one log is 12+4+4+100 = 120 bytes. The maximum size of a document is 4MB, so maximum amount of logs per user is 4MB/120bytes = 33,333. If assumed that a user logs 10 purchases per day, then the 4MB limit is reached in 33,333/10 = 3,333 days ~ 9 years. Well, 9 years is probably fine, but what if we needed to store even more data? What if the user logs 100 purchases per day?

What is the other option here? Do I have to normalize this fully?

```
# option 2: normalized
product = { id, name, price }
log = { id, user_id, product_id, quantity, datetime, comment }
user = { id, name }
```

Meh. We are back to relational.

Comment: Why do you need 12 bytes for a product ID? Maybe you can use a 32-bit  (or less) sequence?

Comment: You can also move the comments to a separate collection and reference the comments by id.

Comment: Oh, nice.. so manually generate the ids by auto-incrementing? Where would you store the last assigned id value?

Comment: @Diederik, moving the comments out would be a huge deal! But I guess it would require doing two queries to get logs and their comments.

Answer (score 3):

if the size is the main concern, you can go ahead with option 2 with mongo [DbRef](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References).

```
     logs : [{ product_id_1, quantity, datetime, comment },
             { product_id_2, quantity, datetime, comment },
             ... ,
             { product_id_n, quantity, datetime, comment }]
```

and embed this logs inside user using Dbref, something like

```
       var log = {product_id: "xxx", quantity:"2", comment:"something"}
       db.logs.save(log)
       var user= { id:"xx" name : 'Joe', logs : [ new DBRef('logs ', log._id) ] }
       db.users.save(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, option 2 is your best bet. Yes, you're back to a relational model, but then, your data is best modeled that way. I don't see a particular downside to option 2, its your data that is requiring you to go that way, not a bad design process.